# I want to be able to create a polynomial function using the data frame column names as terms and the column values as their power raised to it

Tags: pandas

I want to be able to create a polynomial function using the data frame column names as terms and the column values as their powers raised, I've added an example below on what I am looking for, but unfortunately running out of ideas on how to do it

[image]

just to add to this, I have a data file separately with the column names which I will be feeding in, i just wanna be able to iter through each row and create a final function, not sure if it's possible but hardcoding this is a pain and very time consuming, any inputs are helpful

Comment: I have a data frame defining the function with it's terms and degrees, I am suppose to build a polynomial function using that dataframe , I don't have the code to begin with . I want the function to be created with it's terms as the column names as I have defined above  (function=...) Part

Comment: in the second yellow product it should be `Term3**2` according to your sample data

Comment: Let me try coming up with more description on the above data frame that I have defined

Comment: Yes @stef it should be 2, do you know how I can arrive there, just a hint would do

Comment: Yes I'll go thought it and see if that helps, please give me some time

Comment: no problem :), I just thought that you didn't see it yet when you wrote 'do you know how I can arrive there'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `df` for instance as:

```
   coefficient  Term1  Term2
0           25      1      0
1           36      2      0
2          -16      0      0
3            4      2      1
```

and a dataframe `dfv` with values:

```
   Term1  Term2
0      0      1
1      2      0
2      3      0
```

you can do

```
dfv.apply(lambda x: (np.c_[df.coefficient, x.to_numpy()**df.iloc[:,1:]]).prod(1).sum(), 1)
```

to get

```
0    -16
1    178
2    383
```

---

Full reproducible example with your sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
term_cols = [f'Term{i}' for i in range(1,8)]
df = pd.DataFrame([[ 25,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
                   [ 36,   2,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,   1],
                   [-16,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   2],
                   [  4,   2,   1,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0]],
                  columns=['coefficient']+term_cols)

dfv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (3,len(term_cols))), columns=term_cols)

print(dfv[term_cols].apply(lambda x: (np.c_[df.coefficient, x.to_numpy()**df[term_cols]]).prod(1).sum(), 1))
```

Result:

```
0       75
1      985
2    37220
```

---

Update: as per request in comment, here the same as formula:

```
s = ''
for r in df.iterrows():
    r = r[1].loc[r[1].ne(0)]
    s += f'{r[0]:+d}*' + '*'.join([f'(dfv.loc[i,"{k}"]**{v})' if v > 1 else f'(dfv.loc[i,"{k}"])' for k,v in zip(r[1:].index.tolist(), r[1:].tolist())])
    
print(s)

for i in dfv.index:
    print(eval(s))
```

Output:

```
+25*(dfv.loc[i,"Term1"])+36*(dfv.loc[i,"Term1"]**2)*(dfv.loc[i,"Term3"]**2)*(dfv.loc[i,"Term7"])-16*(dfv.loc[i,"Term6"])*(dfv.loc[i,"Term7"]**2)+4*(dfv.loc[i,"Term1"]**2)*(dfv.loc[i,"Term2"])*(dfv.loc[i,"Term3"])

75
985
37220
```

Comment: Kindly bear with me for 2-3 hrs, i'll try using this and will get back to you

Comment: Hey @Stef, i'm trying this out at the moment . Meanwhile i wanted to ask , is there any chance to have the function printed like i have in the picture attached in the question

Comment: This would be possble of course if you just [iter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) through your dataframe and assemble a string with the expression. But for what end? You'll then have to use `eval` to evaluate the string expression. Using the numpy approach I showed is much easier and faster.

Comment: I do understand that i will be able to evaluate the function which happens to be the major goal, but i am trying to cross check the function as well to see what it is printing which turns out to be a subtask, for future references and thank you so very much. I'm at the last stage of checking the above implementation idea of yours, looks very promising, i am just creating a fake data set to see how good it works

Comment: Hey @Stef, could you please guide me through with an example code on how to proceed with this idea of building a function and not evaluating it directly, i seem to have gotten lost from the last 3 hours

Comment: @MohammedNadeem sure, please see my updated answer

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so very much for saving my day :), next time i post a question i'll first check with you , you have the least time complex answers. thanks again